# Manage connected android clients on C# server

Tags: c#, android, ssl, server

I have Android clients connecting to a secure C# server. I can send and receive data to and from both.

What I would like to be able to do is keep track of each android client. I'm doing this via MAC address for now, but later I will have a unique ID that is more permanent.

I am successfully sending the MAC address and receiving it, but I would like any ideas on how I can store the MAC address to later send specific messages to that device to which it belongs.

Right now I'm store the MAC addresses in a list but I'm not sure is the best way.

Comment: You mean how to persist the identifier, or hold it in memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done something similar and I just keep track of their addresses with a database and  I use a stored procedure to keep track if they are connected..if they disconnect and then reconnect then I set it to closed in the database and don't allow the same address to be connected twice. .